# Why "factor" is not plural in "two-factor authentication?"

Tags: grammatical-number, compound-adjectives

In Information Technology, we often see something that looks like a compound adjective, pairing a number and a noum. Some examples are [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915), [two-step verification](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome) and [twelve-factor app](https://12factor.net/). I always found it amusing that the noun itself is not plural.

Why isn't it named, for example, "two-factors authentication?" Is there a rule for that construct? If so, what's its name?

(My theory is that it probably came from [multi-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication), for example, in which there is some sense in the format, but I don't know for sure.)

Comment: Compare "twelve-part documentary."

Comment: English rarely uses plurals for adjectivals, even when there is no singular noun form - scissor kick, pant leg.